# SQLite Insert is not working in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a dialog and a contextual Save menu, which displays Save when I select an Item. When I click on Save nothing happens and nothing is saved only on this table. I have checked Database missing commas etc. seems ok

I call the InsertRecord like that:

```
long SaveResult = mHelper.InsertRecord(Cat,GrName,Que,Ans,Det,Gd);
                if(SaveResult==-1)
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "New row added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but nothing is saved

The following is in my Database helper file

```
public long InsertRecord(String Cat, String Grp, String Que, String Ans, String Det, int Gd) throws SQLiteException {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("rcrdCat", Cat);
    cv.put("rcrdGrp",Grp);
    cv.put("rcrdQue", Que);
    cv.put("rcrdAns", Ans);
    cv.put("rcrdDet",Det);
    cv.put("g_id",Gd);

    long myid=db.insert("records", null, cv);

    return myid;
}
```

Comment: Try temporarily replacing db.insert db.insertOrThrow to see why it's failing to insert.  As a side note, you should really be following java naming conventions; all methods should start with a lowercase character.

Comment: are you getting any exceptions that is causing to fail to insert? if yes, can you post the error log?

Comment: I am not getting any exception it just do nothing Displaying the Something Went Wrong

Comment: I think I mispelled a row field, hmmm but it didnt crash on db.insert why?

Comment: it will be helpful to see your SQL string....

Comment: @WolfBane Why "temporarily"?

Comment: its more secure to have it db.insertOrThrow?

Comment: show me your onCreate method

Comment: @MrTeacher It's a choice, i prefer to handle the results returned from db.insert rather than catching an exception.  If it fails you may not want to know why, and as your original code has db.insert i assume you don't want insertOrThrow.  However for debugging the issue, i suggest you call insertOrThrow to see if any exceptions are thrown.